# Keyboard mapping in Java

Tags: java, windows, keyboard-events

I'm writing a **Java** application to change keyboard bindings in windows. I am using a registry hack to change them. But I have run into 2 problems:

1.How can I know which keys are available in the keyboard?
             I mean different keyboards have different keys (115 -130). How should my application know which keys are available?

2.One key in my keyboard seems to call multiple keyPressed events with 4 key scan codes. How do I address this behavior?

Comment: Your first question can't be done with pure Java.  I imagine on X systems, you can make use of [setxkbmap -print](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setxkbmap), though you'll still have to parse the xkb layout and/or symbol files yourself.  Your second question can be addressed by storing the [timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#getWhen--) of each KeyEvent you receive.  If a value is within a (heuristic) small number of milliseconds of the previous one, it's part of a multi-scan-code key.

Comment: @VGR Thank you. This is more of a windows related question. I am using the registry hack described here [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/) But I don't know how to use a multi-scan-code-key to the registry. Should I add one of them ? or all of them?